# Why hibernate search deletes the index directories (master/slave config)

Tags: hibernate-search

I don't want to rebuild the indexes everytime my application starts but master directory provider ([FSMasterDirectoryProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/api/org/hibernate/search/store/FSMasterDirectoryProvider.html) line# 124/125) deletes the index files when it bootstraps.

Any idea how i can skip that so i can reuse the existing indexes after redeploy / restart of my application?

Comment: It's not deleting the indexes, it's deleting the "current1" and/or "current2" marker files in the source directory, then creating a new marker file to point at the current index directory.  The indexes themselves are left alone.

Comment: Thanks. Now i dont know how the index files like (_0.fdx, _0.fdt, etc) gets cleaned up after i redeploy the application. Everytime i do a fresh deployment in my tomcat the files under "1" or "2" (whichever is current) gets deleted.

Comment: finally, found that our deployment script was cleaning the index folder everytime we do redeploy. do you want to post the answer?

Comment: My comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes so people know that indexes are never deleted but just the marker files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes are not deleted when the application is bootstrapped, it's deleting the "current1" and/or "current2" marker files in the source directory, then creating a new marker file to point at the current index directory. The indexes themselves are left alone.